# Should I stop transaction log backups during a full backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two SQL Agent jobs which are scheduled to run at different intervals. The first job runs a full backup once a day. The second job runs transaction log backups every fifteen minutes.

As the database has grown, the full backup is taking longer than originally planned (even with compression). And I've noticed from my logs that the transaction log backups are now running at the same time.

Should I change the schedule of the transaction log backup so that doesn't run when the full backup is running? Does it matter?

Comment: as others mentioned no need to change your schedule and no conflict, even i prefer to have log backup during full back up because what if the full backup fails due to space constraint? And an Immediate failure at the time full backup, your log backup will save the day!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you can see in this table, there is no conflict between Full backup and Log backup. They can occur at same time, and, when log backup completes, log will not be cleaned until full backup (or diff backup) completes.

[image]

> Not all administrative tasks are allowed to run concurrently. In the table below, a black circle indicates two operations that cannot run in a database at the same time.

**References:**

[Concurrent Administrative Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189315(v=sql.105))

Comment: That is one of those tables that you just want to save for later.  Thanks for the link. +1

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. There is no need to make any changes. The full database backup does not corrupt the transaction log and does not truncate it. Only when you make a transaction log backup the transaction log will be truncated.

Comment: Aren't you telling the same thing Alex_L posted a while ago?

Comment: We have similar answers